# C++ overloading increment operator

Tags: c++, object, overloading, increment, operator-keyword

I have a header file which has a date class defined with month day and year variables and overloaded increment method:

```
mydate operator++(int) {
    return mydate(m, d+1, y);
}
```

and the main cpp has the header included, so once I run `cout<<dateXY++;` it shows me the date incremented by one, however, it doesn't keep the value of the object, but rather resets it to original. So if i put `cout<<dateXY;` after the increment, it will show the original date.

Can I modify the operator overloading so that object keeps the value?

Comment: Yes, you can. So, do that (store the incremented value).

Comment: I meant is it possible to do in h file? Of course I can always do date=date++ in main file, but that wasn't my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this function is a member function of the `mydate` class (wouldn't make much sense otherwise), you need to create a temporary instance of `mydate` with the *old* value, increase the value of `this` and return the temporary instance.

Like

```
mydate operator++(int) {
    mydate tmp(m, d, y);
    // set date to date + 1
    return tmp;
}
```

It's how the post-increment operator works, it increments the value but returns the old value before the increment.

Comment: I know how it works, that is why I added that if I print it out afterwards, it isn't incremented :) It is a member of a class of course

Comment: @Norgul It doesn't change because you don't change it. See the comment in the code-snippet in my answer, you need to change `this` object there, not create and return a modified object like you do. I only wrote a comment because I don't know the member variables.